# Saving country name from country field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need country selection field on my form, my models.py:

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And my forms.py:

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class UserContact(forms.Form):
   first_name = forms.CharField(label='your first name', max_length= 10)    
   country = CountryField().formfield()
```

My views:

```
def get_data(request):

      form = UserContact()
      if request.method == 'POST':
             form =  UserContact(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                    ContactForm.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
                    return render(request, '# some url', { 'form': form}
```

My problem is, when I submit the the form, in my admin page, in my ContactForm model, I have my first name that I entered, and just the country code! Not the full name of the country.
I don't know how to do that. But I know that I can get the country name in shell using:

```
>>>from django_countries import countries      
>>>dict(countries)['NZ'] 
>>>'New Zealand'
```

So, for example, I need the New zealand to be saved in my database, not NZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to save a country code instead country name. So, Change your model as below

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class ContactForm(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    country = CountryField()
```

## forms.py

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class UserContact(forms.Form):
   first_name = forms.CharField(label='your first name', max_length= 10)
   country = CountryField().formfield()
```

## after saving the form you can access country name like below

```
obj = ContactForm.objects.get(pk=10) # some random pk
print(obj.country.name)
```

Comment: that works! thank you
but what if I want it to be non-editable in admin page?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I searched and I got nothing useful